# Is the space of probability measures compact or totally bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space (completely metrizable and separable) and $P(X)$ the set of probability measures on $X$. Then $P(X)$ with the weak topology relative to $C_b(X)$ (the space of continuous bounded functions) is also completely metrizable [Bogachev, "Measure Theory II", Theorem 8.9.4]. Denote by $M(X)$ the space of signed Radon measures on $X$ equipped with the same weak topology $w = \sigma(M(X), C_b(X))$. Then $P(X)$ is closed and bounded in $M(X)$. Since $w$ is a weak topology, bounded sets in $M(X)$ are totally bounded / precompact (for the uniform structure induced by the locally convex topology $w$) (*). Since $P(X)$ is completely metrizable, it is also complete in the uniform structure of $w$. Therefore, $P(X)$ is a complete totally bounded uniform space and such spaces are compact. However, if $X$ is not compact, then $P(X)$ is not compact as well! Contradiction?

Where is the flaw in the above argumentation?

(*) ["In a locally convex space endowed with the weak topology the precompact sets are exactly the bounded sets."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space)

Comment: Are you sure that the sentence "Since $P(X)$ is completely metrizable, it is also complete in the uniform structure of $w$" is correct? If you have a topological *vector space* with topology given by a *translation invariant* metric $d$ under which the space is complete, then it is also complete with respect to the uniform structure. I am not sure that you can drop the translation invariance of the metric, or the assumption that you have a TVS.

Comment: @PhoemueX You may be right - this seems to be the only flaw in the chain of reasoning. I think, I just applied the "topological vector space" version you mentioned. So, $(P(X), w)$ is complete in a metric compatible with $w$ $\not\Rightarrow$ $P(X)$ is complete in the uniform structure of $w$?

[Regarding translation-invariance, a metrizable topological vector space is also metrizable by a translation-invariant metric. If a metrizable topological vector space is complete in its uniform structure then it is complete in all compatible translation-invariant metrics.]

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue. For instance, every *open* set of a complete metric space is also completely metrizable, but this does not mean that it is complete w.r.t. the "original" metric (which is true if and only if the set is closed).